# play the same sound in android without waiting for the previous to end

Tags: android, audio

guys scenario is that suppose i click a button, the sound plays and within the duration of that track i again click the button and want to play it from the beginning. i tried with the following code, but no success. 
code is :

```
public class SoundtestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 MediaPlayer mp;
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
     mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gun_shot);
    Button click=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    click.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mp.isPlaying())
                mp.reset();
            mp.start();
        }
    }));
       }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

```
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
                mp.start();
            }

        });
```

Or replace mp.start(); by mp.reset(); in this code

Answer (score 1):

Best way and the easiest way is = 
mp.setLooping(true);
And yes it does work, just simply add this line after mp.start() and nothinfg else is required

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `comment` the following lines and `shift your Media player instance` in the button's listener method, bingo your done with multiple media players playing parallel to each other

```
Button click=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
click.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gun_shot); // ADD THIS LINE HERE

        if(mp.isPlaying()){ 
            mp.stop();           //ADDED TO STOP FIRST
            mp.release();        //ADDED TO RELEASE RESOURCES
    }
        mp.start();
    }
}));
```

Comment: have tried that before sir
but after few multiple touches it stops playing :/

Comment: can u provide the LOG that is produced when the media player stops playing, try with MediaPlayer.create(); called once in the onCreate(), please provide log

Comment: this is the LOG :

06-18 10:18:21.082: E/MediaPlayer(848): error (-19, 0)
06-18 10:18:21.092: E/MediaPlayer(848): Error (-19,0)
06-18 10:18:21.282: E/MediaPlayer(848): error (-19, 0)
06-18 10:18:21.294: E/MediaPlayer(848): Error (-19,0)
06-18 10:18:21.462: E/MediaPlayer(848): error (-19, 0)<br/><br/>
06-18 10:18:21.462: E/MediaPlayer(848): Error (-19,0)
06-18 10:18:38.636: D/dalvikvm(848): GREF has increased to 201
06-18 10:18:38.662: E/MediaPlayer(848): error (-19, 0)
06-18 10:18:38.672: E/MediaPlayer(848): Error (-19,0)
06-18 10:18:38.872: E/MediaPlayer(848): error (-19, 0)

Comment: There is some limit to the media player instances that can be allowed that is the reason you are getting the error moreover the documentaion says like this `When done with the MediaPlayer, you should call release(), to free the resources. If not released, too many MediaPlayer instances will result in an exception.`

Comment: Please have a look at the edited version of the snippet, i realized that you simply wanted to play the same sound again from begining, and not multiple instances of the same sound.

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue after adding the lines as
      `   @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gun_shot); // ADD THIS LINE HERE

            if(mp.isPlaying()){ 
                mp.stop();           //ADDED TO STOP FIRST
                mp.release();        //ADDED TO RELEASE RESOURCES
        }
            mp.start();
        }`